# Doxygen: ObjectiveC protocols of a class does not appear in HTML

Tags: ios, objective-c, doxygen

I have an ObjectiveC class using some protocols.
I use Doxygen to create documentation.

```
@interface MyView : UIView
< MyInterface1
, MyInterface2 >
...
```

But generated HMTL is

```
Inherits UIView.
```

How can I get the protocols used in this class and displayed in HTML export ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I recall there were no problems with this. Doxygen is just a parser, it might got confused with those breaks, try to use *regular* syntax, like

```
@interface MyView: UIView <MyInterface1, MyInterface2>
```

Comment: It works great! We have to put all protocols on same line. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool. If answer works for you it is a good citizen practice on SO to mark answer as accepted and vote up it, so community members have better chance to find it if same issue appeared. Thanks.